# m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME); Assertion Failed: at afxwin1.inl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, static-libraries

I am getting some weird error as `Assert Failed` `f:\dd\...\include\afxwin1.inl`. I am searched in Google some solutions, some solutions are for commenting this line (`m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);`) in Release mode to make it work. But after commenting that line I am getting some more errors.

I have taken a dialog based MFC application. It was working absolutely fine when it was an `application.exe`. My requirement is to make it `static library` and I will have another `console application` which will become main `application.exe`, I am calling `InitInstance` from that `.exe`. Once it fatches the line,

```
CDialogDlg::CDialogDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CDialogDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);

}
```

It throws above error.

In my `application.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DialogDlg.h"
#include "Dialog.h"
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include <afxinet.h> 
CDialogApp theApp;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //CInitApp cpp;
    theApp.InitInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

`Dialog.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dialog.h"
#include "DialogDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CDialogApp

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDialogApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CDialogApp construction

CDialogApp::CDialogApp()
{
    m_dwRestartManagerSupportFlags = AFX_RESTART_MANAGER_SUPPORT_RESTART;
}
//CDialogApp theApp;// I have commented this code as I am declaring it in mainapplication

BOOL CDialogApp::InitInstance()
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    AfxEnableControlContainer();
    CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;
    //SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

    CDialogDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
}
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
    }

    if (pShellManager != NULL)
    {
        delete pShellManager;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I have commented `CDialogApp theApp;` line in `Dialog.cpp` as I am calling it in `mainapplication .exe` The problem happen when it reaches `CDialogDlg dlg;`.
Please help me how to resolve this error.

In other way is it possible to set a dialog based application as static library. If yes then why am I getting this error. I have tried making the main application in Windows and console based too. Please find the screenshot for better understing, what am I trying to do.[image]

Comment: When moving the MFC code to a library you have to manage the module state, so that module-private resources get properly resolved. Details can be found at [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft1t4bbc.aspx) and [Managing the State Data of MFC Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0asx94f7.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static library does not contain any resources, but your dialog code attempts to load icon and dialog template resources. Did you move the resources into the console app? (I don't know if that would work, but it certainly won't work if you don't.)

The conventional and supported solution is to put the dialog code into a DLL instead of a static lib. A DLL can contain the resources.

Comment: I did not move resources into console app. But still I am providing or including resource header file where ever required

Comment: The resource header file contains ID numbers only. It does not contain any resources like icons, etc. Lib files do not support resources. Only exe files and DLL files support resources.

Comment: I have the same problem. My program is not a static library, and I've checked that the resource exists, but the problem still arise