# MFC assertion failed when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, assert

I'm not familiar with MFC but currently I must continue a project that was written in MFC. Now I'm having trouble with the following line when debugging

```
m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon (IDR_MAINFRAME);
```

It always stops after the error "Assertion Failed: at afxwin1.inl". If I put a breakpoint there I saw a NULL icon handle. I tried running in release mode and it worked just fine although the handle is still NULL. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367464/m-hicon-afxgetapp-loadiconidr-mainframe-assertion-failed-at-afxwin1-inl) but my program is not a static library. It's a program that use a dll to connect to a CAN bus device. And the resource `IDR_MAINFRAME` is already in the project. It contains the default MFC icons. How can I solve this problem?

---

I've tried debugging and see that `pModuleState` changes between the first load program name call and the second load icon call. The first call returns successfully because pModuleState points to an object that has valid handle. But in the icon load call, pModuleState points to some object contains NULL handle. I also tried putting `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ));` right above the `LoadIcon()` call but the problem still arises

---

I've known the cause of this problem

```
UINT __cdecl RunCPRead(LPVOID pParam)
{
    CMyDlg *thisclass = (CMyDlg *)pParam;

    while (thisclass->m_Start)
    {   
        thisclass->GetData();
    }
    return 0;
}

AfxBeginThread(&RunCPRead, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);
```

After the `GetData()` call in `RunCPRead`, the control flows directly to CMyDlg's contructor although there's no object being created or copied

```
CMyDlg::CMyDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CMyDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}
```

and then fails at the assignment to m_hIcon with the error "access violation while reading". I've seen the disassembly, it was the line `mov dword ptr [esi+90h], eax` and it's inherently a write to memory.

I don't know why. How can I solve this?

Comment: Assertions are disabled in release mode, that's why the program appears to run fine in that mode. You probably should add an icon with identifier `IDR_MAINFRAME` to your resources file.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: In the resource list there is already `IDR_MAINFRAME` with many icons in it

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure these resources are actually embedded in your executable? (You can open the executable itself in resources view to double-check.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes, the resource is also embedded in the exe file

Answer (score 0):

The MFC code need the correct module handle to load the resource.
Please try to read Afx**G/S**etResourceHandle.

Comment: `AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);` will call `AfxGetResourceHandle()`. That was automatic generated by the default MFC dialog project settings

Comment: LoadIcon returns NULL, so it is probably your current resource handle is not correct. In this case, you need to call AfxSetResourceHandle with the right module handle before calling LoadIcon.

Comment: The ID is right. I've check the exe file and there is an icon with ID 128, which is IDR_MAINFRAME in the resource.h file. I haven't touch any of that code because it was generated automatically

Comment: where is your LoadIcon call located?

Comment: As I said, it's the default VS generated code, so it's at the main dialog's contructor

Answer (score 0):

By default MFC uses the resource handle of the main application, not of the DLL. If you are making the call in the DLL then add this line at the start of the exported DLL function:

AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ));

There is more information about this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9d5yh5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've tried this but this does not help because the call is from the main exe. It's the default code generated when creating an MFC dialog project. Inside LoadIcon or some sub function call there is already a AFX_MANAGE_STATE call

Comment: The first call to `AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);` ended successfully. It failed when the program jumps to the contructor again and I don't know why. Please see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

Assertion Errors in MFC usually happens when wrong settings are set.

go to project settings > linker > System and change subsystem to (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) this solution solved my own problem.